# What are the criteria for having a question tweeted by StackMovies?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that the site has a twitter, StackMovies. And on this twitter, my question was tweeted. Is there criteria anywhere listed to determine what questions get tweeted? I'm just wondering, so that we're not tweeting questions that get voted down a lot, or duplicates.

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 11):

The bot is only meant to tweet "interesting" questions - based on some algorithm.   I don't know the details of the algorithm, but I am aware that it does have a "score must be greater than zero" rule in it:

[From Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94429/how-did-this-get-tweeted)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any question that gets an upvote gets tweeted. At least, it does on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - that would make sense where we only get an average of 7 questions a day.

Comment: But just cause it's upvoted, doesn't mean it should be tweeted.